# IndexOutOfBoundsException? Reading from txt file and creating 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have been trying to tackle this assignment for the past 5-8 hours now with no avail. 
I was assigned to read a txt file that contains about 50 lines of "carModel,carColor" , and create an [8]x[8] 2d array that has every car model on the top of the matrix, and every car color on the left of the 2d matrix, both sorted. Then for every time that certain "carModel,carColor" get chosen, their respective carModel and carColor get updated by 1. Like a car inventory sheet.

I have created a 2D array that is a String, from two separate ArrayList and filled the null spaces where all the zeros are supposed to go, the the String "0". But now I am having trouble reading the file so that it updates the original [8]x[8] String array every time a specific "carModel,carColor" is chosen. Where am I going wrong here, what can I do to make this easier/more organized?

This is my current code for the entire assignment:

```
public class Cars1 {
public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
{
    String [][] cars = new String [8][8]; 
    ArrayList <String> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    colors.add("BLUE  ");
    colors.add("BLACK ");
    colors.add("BROWN ");
    colors.add("GREEN ");
    colors.add("RED   ");
    colors.add("SILVER");
    colors.add("WHITE ");
    Collections.sort(colors);
    ArrayList <String> models = new ArrayList<>();
    models.add("Escape  ");
    models.add("Explorer");
    models.add("F150    ");
    models.add("F250    ");
    models.add("Flex    ");
    models.add("Mustang ");
    models.add("Taurus  ");
    Collections.sort(models);
    cars [0][0] = "_____  ";
    for (int a = 1; a < cars.length; a++)
    {
        cars[0][a] = (models.get(a-1)) + " ";
    }
    for (int b = 1; b < cars.length; b++)
    {
        cars[b][0] = (colors.get(b-1)) + " ";
    }
    for (int fir = 1; fir < cars.length; fir++)
    {
        for (int sec = 1; sec < cars[1].length; sec++)
        {
            if (cars[fir][sec] == null)
            {
                cars[fir][sec] = "0        ";
            }
        }
    }       
    for (int first = 0; first < cars.length; first++)
    {
        for (int second = 0; second < cars[first].length; second++)
        {
            System.out.print(cars[first][second]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }        
    File file = new File ("/Users/blakells/NetBeansProjects/Examples/cars.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    String ab = sc.nextLine();
    int[][]count = new int [8][8];
       while (ab != null) 
       {

   String model = ab.substring(0,ab.indexOf(",")).toLowerCase();
   // I get the exception here
   String color = ab.substring(ab.indexOf((",")+1)).toLowerCase();
   int row = colors.indexOf(color.toLowerCase());
   int col = models.indexOf(model.toLowerCase());
   count[row][col]++;        
}
}
}
```

Comment: It would for sure help to know where exactly the exception occurrs, like which line causes it.

Comment: @Philipp edited,sorry!

Comment: are you sure that the string ab is always in the expected format? maybe there is a blank line or something like that.